# EF adds another entry when saving context changes even if it exists

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
public class Parent
{
   public int ID;
   public string Name;
   public int Child_ID;
   public Child Child;
}

public class Child
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public int Parent_ID;
    public Parent Parent;
}
```

I have a little issue with ef when it comes to the folowing scenario:

I added a parent with a child but if I extract a `Child c` (with `c.Parent == null`) and then it's `Parent p` (2 queries) and then do:

```
Child.Parent = p;
context.SaveChanges();
```

It will add a new `Parent` in the database even if `p` exists. Is there a way to override this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are working with a detached entity. If you don't get the parent entity from the same instance of your constext, when you assign the `Parent` to the `Child` instance, EF  considers this to be an unrecognized entity and its default behavior for unrecognized entities with no state is to mark them as `Added`. So, again, the `Parent` will be inserted into the database when `SaveChanges` is called.

To resolve that problem, try this:

```
context.Parents.Attach(p);
Child.Parent = p;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Alternatively, in place of `context.Parents.Attach(p)`, you could set the state of the `Parent` before or after the fact, explicitly setting its state to `Unchanged`:

```
context.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

If you want to learn more about this topic, I suggest you read this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx)